# MIPS Asm - Invalid/illegal second operand

Tags: assembly, mips

What I'm trying to do here is calculate an offset and that add it to an array, to store a value at that position in the array. I've seen this done like so:

```
board: .space 36

move  $s0, $a0                # Save our arg (cell offset) in $s0

li    $t0,  6                 # Store the size of the board in $t0
div   $s0,  $t0               # Cell Offset / Board Size
mflo  $s1                     # $s1 is our cell row index
mfhi  $s2                     # $s2 is our cell col index

lb     $t1, board + 0($s0)     # Load current cell's value in $t1
```

The following line,

```
lb     $t1, board + 0($s0)     # Load current cell's value in $t1
```

is causing the following error when I try to compile:

```
Error: Invalid/illegal second operand.
```

I've seen this done in other MIPS assembly programs, so I'm not sure why this does not work.

Comment: You forgot to mention which assembler you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assembler is not smart enough to tell that `board + 0` is the displacement to use wrt register `$s0`.

The workaround would be for you to compute that displacement, i.e:

```
lb     $t1, board($s0)     # Load current cell's value in $t1
```

Here i removed the `+ 0` in `board+0` as the displacement is exactly the same. Your assembler should understant at least that format, *label(register)*

Answer (score 1):

You can only do constant operations at assembly time. `board + 0($s0)` is not a constant operation because assembler has no way to know what value `0($s0)` will have as it is a runtime-dependent value.